# Multiple use of jQuery Upload Preview library

Tags: javascript, jquery

At this moment, I'm using this library for image preview: [jQuery Upload Preview](https://github.com/opoloo/jquery_upload_preview/). Is it possible to use it multiple times on one page without duplicating preview?

```
$.uploadPreview({
    input_field: ".image-upload",
    preview_box: ".image-preview",
    label_field: ".image-label"
});

$("#addNew").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $("body").append( '<div class="image-preview"><label for="image-upload" class="image-label">Choose file</label><input type="file" name="thumbnail[]" accept="image/*" class="image-upload" /></div>' );
});
```

Here is demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpwyrs6L/)
Or maybe someone has good alternative for this?
I need to use it multiple times dynamic like this and have the possibility to preload images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to give each element a unique id and call the plugin after inserting each one into the DOM.

Here's a kind of kludgy way to do it:

```
var id = 1;

$("#addNew").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("body").append( '<div id="image-preview-'+id+'" class="image-preview"><label id="image-label-'+id+'" for="image-upload-'+id+'" class="image-label">Choose file</label><input type="file" id="image-upload-'+id+'" name="thumbnail[]" accept="image/*" class="image-upload" /></div>' );

  $.uploadPreview({
    input_field: "#image-upload-" + id,
    preview_box: "#image-preview-" + id,
    label_field: "#image-label-" + id
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/von9zL1g/1/

Comment: @Vertisan sorry about that, here's the correct jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/von9zL1g/1/